# Anti-Positivist Texts

Tags: reference-request

I am hoping someone can recommend good texts concerning interpretivist epistemology.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would there be an anti-something textbook? Or do you just mean critiques of positivism? And some context would be helpful, you want critique of positivism on what specifically, and what is the overarching goal, so to speak?

Comment: It's also known as interpretivism. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipositivism. I prefer not to define it in terms of its antithesis.

Comment: e.g. https://www.springer.com/us/book/9789027715678. But I don't know much about the subject.

Comment: Those two are pretty different things, the first refers to separate methodology for human sciences, the second to critique of the traditional positivism in philosophy of science. Which is why I asked about your focus and goals.

Comment: My bad. I am more interested in the second. My focus is on epistemological underpinnings of the methodology, not the methodology itself. I am interested in the philosophy of science in general, but I am really interested in a point of view which critiques logical positivism in the philosophy of science.

Comment: Critical section of [Wikipedia's Logical Positivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_positivism#Critics) gives a passable short review of the matter with references to book treatments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85904/discussion-between-dean-young-and-conifold).

Comment: John Zammito, [A Nice Derangement of Epistemes : Post-positivism in the Study of Science from Quine to Latour](https://books.google.it/books?id=iXxK6e07ciUC&printsec=frontcover) (2004)

Comment: See also [Émile Meyerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Meyerson) and [Gaston Bachelard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaston_Bachelard).

Comment: If any of you post this as an answer I would gladly accept it by the way.